# Clean fails on Oracle

Tags: oracle, flyway

When I run the clean command against an Oracle database I get this error.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DROP_JOB'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Im using Oracle 10.2.0.4.0 and Flyway 3.1

**EDIT**

I used a legacy database.

First I run

```
flyway baseline -Dflyway.baselineVersion=1 -Dflyway.baselineDescription="Base version"
```

Then I added this script

```
CREATE TABLE "SMTAPP"."EC_KODY_VYKONU"
(
    "ID" NUMBER(9, 0) NOT NULL, 
    "NAZOV" NVARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE "SMTAPP"."EC_MATERIALY"
(
    "ID" NUMBER(9, 0) NOT NULL, 
    "NAZOV" NVARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
    "IS_ROZTOK" NUMBER(1, 0) NOT NULL 
);

CREATE SEQUENCE "SMTAPP"."EC_KODY_VYKONU_SEQ" INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOMAXVALUE NOCYCLE;

ALTER TABLE "SMTAPP"."EC_KODY_VYKONU"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_52eece2411997559a4bb900877d" PRIMARY KEY
    ( 
        "ID" 
    );

ALTER TABLE "SMTAPP"."EC_MATERIALY"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_86fb16745239d69a3bd73a82d1a" PRIMARY KEY
    ( 
        "ID" 
    );
```

Then I run

```
flyway migrate
```

And now when I run clean command the error pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably in one of your scripts where you call DROP_JOB you have less or more parameters than it needs as the error shows.

Like:

```
DROP_JOB(VARCHAR2 p_param)
... procedure body
```

was called like

```
DROP_JOB(param1, param2);
```

or

```
DROP_JOB();
```

Things to do:
 - correct the script
 - run a flyway repair
 - run the migration

Comment: But there isnt any script with a DROP_JOB call. Does the clean command remove only object created with the migration command or does it remove all object in the current schema ?

Comment: @user49126 can you update your question adding the script? I could guess only from what I saw, maybe the call of DROP_JOB happened in some package, so it might happen you need to inspect your package procedures.

Comment: @user49126 I see, your problem is not that trivial, I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23767341/1983814) maybe it is related.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug. Please file an issue in the Flyway [Issue Tracker](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues).